# Embeded youtube player show black screen on mobile

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I have a wordpress site that I added to him an html code for a video to embed on the front page. This is the code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can see the video clearly on desktop, but on mobile (Chrome and another browser) I only see a black screen that is unclickable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. This makes your iframe responsive.

```css
.iframe-container{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
 margin-bottom:15px
}

.fw-iframe{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
 <iframe class="fw-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DSR4gRfWmW0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Adjust the padding, margin and width accordingly.